# Build AllJoyn for iOS with bitcode enabled

Tags: ios, xcode7, alljoyn

I am creating an IOS app that uses the AllJoyn library. The alljoyn_darwin xcode project provided with AllJoyn to build the AllJoyn does not have all of the options in the build settings that I have on my xcode project for my app. The enable bit code option in the AllJoyn project is not there.
I have tried to add the user defined setting `ENABLE_BITCODE` and set it to `YES` however this has had no effect.

Is there a way to build the AllJoyn libraries for iOS with bitcode enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. The last version of Alljoyn to support iOS is 15.04, which is tested against iOS 8.1 (https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/supported-platforms), which predates Bitcode.

Also, I think I remember that using Alljoyn means using libstdc++, which I'm pretty sure can't be compiled in a project using Bitcode.